# RDD to HDFS - authentication error - RetryInvocationHandler

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos

I have an RDD that I wish to write to HDFS.

`data.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://path/vertices")`

This returns:
`WARN RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over null. Not retrying because try once and fail.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]`

I have checked KERBEROS and it is properly authenticated.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is you kerberos using Keytab or Login and Password?

Comment: It uses Keytab Thiago.

Comment: Did you check the Hadoop `core-site.xml` that Spark driver uses, and does it explicitly state that clients **must** use Kerberos? Because that error message is typical of lame Hadoop conf on client side.

Comment: Hi Samson. in the `core-site.xml` I have ```<property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
      <value>kerberos</value>
    </property>``` and ```<property>
      <name>hadoop.http.authentication.type</name>
      <value>kerberos</value>
    </property>``` and ```<property>
      <name>hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>``` Does this satisfy?

Comment: I've also tried adding `--keytab` to `spark-submit` as per  https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually related to how you [reference](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.0.0/bk_ambari-views/content/Cluster_Configuration_Custom.html) a file in HDFS when using `kerberos`.

Rather than `hdfs://<HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>`

It is `webhdfs://<HOST>:<HTTP_PORT>`

Answer (score 0):

Well,

You need to check your path `/etc/security/keytabs` and check if your spark keytab is there.

This path is the recommended to the Kerberos configuration. Maybe it can be in other path.

But the most important, this keytab should be in all workers machines in the same path.

Other thing that you can check is the configuration file of Spark that should be installed in:

```
SPARK_HOME/conf
```

This folder should have the spark conf file `spark-defaults.conf` this conf file need to have this stuffs:

```
spark.history.kerberos.enabled true
spark.history.kerberos.keytab /etc/security/keytabs/spark.keytab
spark.history.kerberos.principal user@DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

Comment: Thanks Thiago. I can see it in master and all of the worker machines. Hmmmm

Comment: In your spark conf the variable spark.history.kerberos.keytab has the path right?

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707722/how-to-add-configuration-file-to-classpath-of-all-spark-executors-in-spark-1-2-0

Comment: Sorry for the delay! So the path of Spark of default instalation should be here: `/etc/spark/conf` But to make it easy it will be in the `SPARK_HOME/conf`

Comment: Thanks Thiago. Does the fact that it says "Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]" mean that it is in the `conf` file? I don't have access to the `conf` file unfortunately!

Comment: @LearningSlowly this probably is. The point is Kerberos ask for authentication when you access Hadoop, Kafka, Hive and etc stuffs in your cluster. You have Kerberos but your Spark doesnt have the option enabled. This is probably the issue. I will update the answer.